# Is grandchild process also child process?

Tags: process

In Unix/Linux terminology, do child processes of a process include grandchild processes of the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a child process `B` is a process created by some other process `A`. Since children of `B` are not created by `A`, they are not children of `A`. See also the wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process).

(And fortunately there is always just a single parent, so there is no chance of incest)

Answer (score 3):

The processes are arranged in a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29), which you can display with `pstree`. By definition, [every process except 0 (PID 1, aka. `init`) has a single parent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent_process). For example, in this process tree `gnome-session` has three *children* and four *descendants* (including the right-most `nm-applet`), plus one parent (as per the definition) and three *ancestors* (`lightdm` twice and then `init`):

```
init─┬─lightdm─┬─Xorg
     │         ├─lightdm─┬─gnome-session─┬─awesome
     │         │         │               ├─nm-applet───{nm-applet}
     │         │         │               ├─ssh-agent
     │         └─2*[{lightdm}]
...
```